# Solana API RPC Devnet query - cluster version query failed

Tags: rpc, solana-cli, cli, devnet, network-health

I have my config RPC URL set as `https://api.devnet.solana.com`

When I do a `solana balance` in CLI,  I get `Error: RPC request error: cluster version query failed: error sending a request for URL (https://api.devnet.solana.com/): error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 61)`

How should I check if the network is down or if something is wrong with my config?

Thanks

Comment: Ok it seems to be responding. Would like to know what I should do in future, where to check or report down?

Comment: nevermind it is not responding again. Am I rate limited? Am not doing anything intensive, just deploying a program. I notice that the frontend is not responding as well, but was not having much trouble before so I don't know if rate limited or network is have issue.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the RPC is down, you can totally use an HTTP request lib (it's still a url) such as **node-fetch** or **axios**. You make a simple GET request to the URL and if the result is a 404 type error it is because the RPC is down